# Is it possible to use Cg shaders in WebGL?

Tags: opengl, webgl, shader, cg-language

I'm aware of that I can use GLSL shaders in WebGL via `attachShader` and `compileShader`, as I did in OpenGL. My problem is: how about shaders written in Cg? On desktop I need `cgc` to compile them, what's the corresponding tool in WebGL world?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to.

You could compile your shaders into GLSL with cgc (`-profile glslv` or `-profile glslf`), then load them anywhere you want. There is, however, slight difference between desktop and ES GLSL (WebGL likely using ES specification), so it may require adding a little hints at the beginning of shader (like `precision mediump float;`, could easily be `#ifdef`'d/).

Of course you can't use some Cg functionality in this case - if it is missing in GLSL, cgc can do nothing. E.g. mapping uniforms to specified registers or settings varyings to specified interpolator.